# Building Dynamic GroupBy Selector Expression Tree With Multiple Properties

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, expression, expression-trees

I am to build a dynamic Expression Tree for GroupBy. All i want to achieve is like this.

```
var NestedGrouped = listOfPerson.GroupByMany(x => x.Name,x=>x.Age).ToList();
```

My Person Class is like :-

```
class Person
{
 public string Name{ get; set; }
 public int Age{ get; set; }
 public float Salary{ get; set; }
}
public class GroupResult
{
        public object Key { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<GroupResult> SubGroups { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        { return string.Format("{0} ({1})", Key, Count); }
 }
 public static class MyEnumerableExtensions
 {
        public static IEnumerable<GroupResult> GroupByMany<TElement>(
            this IEnumerable<TElement> elements,
            params Func<TElement, object>[] groupSelectors)
        {
            if (groupSelectors.Length > 0)
            {
                var selector = groupSelectors.First();

                //reduce the list recursively until zero
                var nextSelectors = groupSelectors.Skip(1).ToArray();
                return
                    elements.GroupBy(selector).Select(
                        g => new GroupResult
                        {
                            Key = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Count(),
                            Items = g,
                            SubGroups = g.GroupByMany(nextSelectors)
                        });
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

For Single Property I am able to build the expression but i want to do GROUPBY
with multiple columns as shown above.
FOR SINGLE PROPERTY :-

```
 ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "lambdaKey");
            var menuProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Name");
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, string>>(menuProperty, parameter);
            var selector = lambda.Compile();
            var result = P1.GroupByMany(selector);// P1 is list of PERSON
```

How to ADD multiple columns in Expression Tree (e.g (x => x.Name,x=>x.Age)).
Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What really is your question? There is no multiple columns in your sample, but list (array) of single columns.

Comment: @IvanStoev I want to dynamically generate expression tree for list of colums which i can pass in GroupByMany.

Comment: There is **no** expression tree **for list of columns** in your sample. The same way you build for single property, you can allocate array and fill each element, then pass the array to GroupByMany. `params Func<TElement, object>[] groupSelectors` is **array of expressions**, not single expression, don't you agree?

Answer (score 2):

`GroupByMany()` accepts array of delegates, one delegate for each key. So, what you need is to create and compile a separate expression for each key.

The code could look something like:

```
private static Func<TElement, object> CreateSelector<TElement>(string key)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TElement), "lambdaKey");
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, key);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, string>>(property, parameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}

public static IEnumerable<GroupResult> GroupByMany<TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> elements,
    params string[] groupKeys)
{
    return elements.GroupByMany(groupKeys.Select(CreateSelector<TElement>).ToArray());
}
```