# Dynamically Group By Property Referenced By String

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So I have a relatively large data set that I want the end user to be able to customize in a way.

Currently data is grouped as follows:

```
var versusHistories =
                from th in db.TeamHistories
                where th.TeamOneName.ToLower() == team.ToLower()
                group th by th.Date
                into grp1
                from grp2 in
                    (from th in grp1
                        group th by th.Event)
                group grp2 by grp1.Key;
```

If I wanted to allow the user to specify the `group by` clauses, how would I do that?

Example:

User navigates to http://example.com/search?team=AbcTeam&grpBy1=TeamTwo&grpBy2=Date

The page then renders this code:

```
var versusHistories =
                from th in db.TeamHistories
                where th.TeamOneName.ToLower() == team.ToLower()
                group th by th.TeamTwo
                into grp1
                from grp2 in
                    (from th in grp1
                        group th by th.Date)
                group grp2 by grp1.Key;
```

How can I dynamically provide this functionality without having to hard code each individual possibility?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332717/building-dynamic-groupby-selector-expression-tree-with-multiple-properties) not similar but will give you Idea how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

With Method Syntax, you can do something like:

```
var versusHistories =
            from th in db.TeamHistories
            where th.TeamOneName.ToLower() == team.ToLower()

if (condition)
{
    versusHistories = versusHistories.GroupBy(g => ..something..);
}
else if (anotherCondition)
{
    versusHistories = versusHistories.GroupBy(g => ..something else..);
}
```

I'm not sure if/how it's possible with pure Query Syntax.

That prevents you from repeating the core query multiple times.

Comment: Seeing as there are 5+ possible properties to group by I would have ~10 if clauses. 5 for the initial group, and 5 for the second group. Doesn't that seem excessive?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete anser but you could try to use reflection and do something like this:

```
var listOfPropertiesToSortBy = new List<string>();
var versusHistories = from th in db.TeamHistories
                      where th.TeamOneName.ToLower() == team.ToLower();

foreach (var property in listOfPropertiesToSortBy ) {
       versusHistories = versusHistories.GroupBy(vh => typeof(TeamHistories).GetProperty(property).GetValue(vh));
}
```

The issue with this is that every time you iterate over the list the new OrderBy statement will override the last. There needs to be a way to say .ThenBy after the first property but I know versusHistories = versusHistories.ThenBy(something) isn't valid. Maybe someone can take this and extend it a bit to work for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe what I am asking is impossible. After writing a similar version to what you have it shows this `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

Comment: You probably want:

.GroupBy(vh => typeof(TeamHistories).GetProperty(property).GetValue(vh))